# Parcel building stops without finishing

Tags: javascript, sass, parcel

I'm trying to use parcel build, but when I type `npx parcel build index.html` i see in console that it started building and after a couple of elements it types `Bundling...` and stops building without error. I tried deleting all old parcel elements, tried reinstalling parcel, tried switching version. Nothing works.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyO1D.png

Answer (score 0):

Probably find out why that was happening, for anybody who got the same problem. The thing is that parcel not smart enough too build files which is not in `src` folder. I was trying to build with this config:

- .parcel-cache
- dist
- node_modules
- styles/style.scss
- index.html
- package.json

Then I created src folder and put there index.html and style.scss, and it finally worked. So if anybody have this problem **just put all code files in *src* folder**, and it would be builded properly